# How to set a plain virtual background on the Jitsi video conference?

Tags: css, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I'm using Jitsi as self-hosted and I'm trying to set a plain virtual background as default for the video conferences. I have added a background image to the `/usr/share/jitsi-meet/images` directory and I have added the custom css below to the `/usr/share/jitsi-meet/css` directory.

```
body.welcome-page{
background:inherit;
overflow:auto
}
.welcome{
background-image: url('/usr/share/jitsi-meet/images/green.jpg');
display:flex;
```

Then I have imported my custom.css file in the empty body.html file that is located in `/usr/share/jitsi-meet` directory as below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css?v=1">
```

However, just my waiting lobby has been changed with this way as below.

[image]

How can I change my video's background?